# when i redirect forcefully http to https it shows redirected you too many times

Tags: .htaccess, http

I apply like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Product/Category/([^/]*)$ /Product/index.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^Pages/([^/]*)$ /Allpages/?Pages=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^Products/([^/]*)$ /Product/ProductPage.php?product=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

but, It shows www.example.com redirected you too many times.

Comment: means what is the exact problem? means this code working or not?

Comment: @bhavinthummar actually i don't know code is working or not

RewriteRule ^Product/Category/([^/]*)$ /Product/index.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^Pages/([^/]*)$ /Allpages/?Pages=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^Products/([^/]*)$ /Product/ProductPage.php?product=$1 [L]

before this code working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay @ravi i have got your problem so please use this solution.

New Code :

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^Product/Category/([^/]*)$ /Product/index.php?category=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^Pages/([^/]*)$ /Allpages/?Pages=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^Products/([^/]*)$ /Product/ProductPage.php?product=$1 [L]


  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
 </IfModule>
```